# granting user permissions to grant other users

Tags: oracle

Please can you advise what grants will achieve this without having to give `GRANT ALL PRIVILEDGES`

```
CREATE USER TEST IDENTIFIED BY TEST;
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE TO TEST;
GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE TO TEST WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT INSERT ANY TABLE TO TEST WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT ANY ROLE TO TEST;

CONNECT TEST/TEST
GRANT INSERT ON SAMPLE.PLAN_A TO SOME ROLE;

                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic premise on Oracle privileges is that you can give permissions on somthing *you* own, or something that *others* own.  "Others" is not specific - it is "anyone not you", hence the 'ANY' term in many of the privileges along these lines.

A mechanism that can be used is a definers rights PL/SQL procedure, ie

```
procedure SAMPLE.GRT is
begin
  execute immediate 'GRANT INSERT ON SAMPLE.PLAN_A TO SOME ROLE';
end;

grant execute on SAMPLE.GRT to TEST;
```

but of course, if you wanted to do this entirely as TEST, then TEST will need 'create ANY procedure' so you've really just shifted the problem.

But that's the way grants work.